# Unexpected classpath behaviour remote deployment of Java application with Netbeans 13

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, remote-debugging

Can anyone help me understand the classpath logic when deploying Java applications to remote hosts?

Netbeans will build, deploy and execute my Java application correctly on a remote Linux (Ubutntu 20.x) host.

Lets say that the executable JAR is deployed and executed in:
/home/user/project/dist

With any supporting library files copied to:
/home/user/project/dist/lib

This all makes sense to me.

However, I wish to read application and log4j2 configuration files. I would think that these should be placed in the same directory as the jar file. However they must be placed in the parent directory:

/home/user/project

Okay... BUT...

If I amend my code to write out a text file (to the executable directory) the resulting text file is written to:

/home/user/project/

<Edited 19Jun22>

I want my deployed application to read the log4j2.xml and configuration files from the same directory that my application writes to. What configuration settings must I change in Netbeans?

Alternatively is there a way to make Netbeans deploy to /home/user/project instead of /home/user/project/dist?

Comment: I'm not understanding your concern. You state that _"If I amend my code to write out a text file (to the executable directory) the resulting text file is written to: /home/user/project/dist"_, but isn't **/home/user/project/dist** your executable directory? If so, what is the problem? Is your concern that the text file your app creates is not being created in the parent directory **/home/user/project**? Please clarify where you want/expect your text file to be created. What is your specific problem? ("_help me understand..._" is off topic here.)

Comment: My apologies. My properties and log4j2.xml files are read from /home/user/project/dist. If my code writes out a text file then it is written into /home/user/project.

Comment: OK, you have described the actual behavior. But update your question with your **specific** problem/question. Just asking _"help me understand"_ and _"What is going on?"_ are vague phrases.